# Why is GPU frame capture not working with Metal?

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

When I click on the camera button to capture and debug the GPU, it just disables the button and nothing else happens. When I then *stop* the app from XCode, the view is (confusingly) switched to Assistant editor, with source code in both views.

Also, I noticed the FPS stays at zero in the debug panel, while I can see video rendered from Metal shaders.

If I run a new example app the GPU debugging works and I can see the FPS at 60. Does anyone know what it could be?

Using Xcode 6.4 and iPhone 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all `insertDebugCaptureBoundary` lines in my project solved it.

Comment: I have a compute only metal application. I have to add insertDebugCaptureBoundary to enable the capture. but even so, the capturing does not look good. I wasn't able to achieve the profiling results as shown in the programming guide.